# Get player instance from THEOPlayer?

Tags: javascript

A video steaming I use uses THEOPlayer and I want to control the player e.g. stop, currentTime, textTrackStyle etc; via the JavaScript API they provide https://www.npmjs.com/package/theoplayer

The doc says you can create a new player instance in this manner:

```
player = new THEOplayer.Player(element);
```

But what I must do is get the already-initialized player instance.

How can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: I've not worked with THEOplayer, but it seems in the docs (https://docs.theoplayer.com/api-reference/web/theoplayer.md) you can get the list of player with `THEOplayer.players` which will return an array of ChromelessPlayers from which you can get the UID of the player and then `const player = THEOplayer.PlayerList.getPlayerByUID(UID);`

Comment: Tested on the THEOplayer demos and it should be: `THEOplayer.players` to get all the players initiated, find the one you are looking for (for e.g.: 5 element in the array) then `const myPlayer = THEOplayer.players.getPlayerByUID(THEOplayer.players[4].uid);`

Comment: Thanks @ArslanSohailBano, I tried it and worked for me ;)